# How to write batch apex?

Tags: apex, batch

I am new to Salesforce. So a help is required from you guyz.

I want to write a Batch Apex, where I want to update some value of Account (lets say Name).

and then from before trigger I have to call this Batch.

How to achieve this??

A help would be very appreciable.

Batch I have written so far

```
   global class AccUpdate implements Database.batchable<sObject>{ 

   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id FROM Account');
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
       List<Account> Scope1 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account];
       for(Account a : scope1){ 
           a.Name = 'Demo Account1'; 
           Scope1.add(a); 
       } 
       update Scope1; 
   }     
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){     
   } 
}
```

Now I want to write a before trigger and I want to call this batch .

How to do that??

Comment: It may be more meaningful to explain what you're trying to achieve and how to do that. Could you explain why you want to kick of a batch from a before trigger context ?

Comment: @user5442 - I have to echo the comments from @Sdry : why do you require the  `before` trigger (instead of the `after` trigger)? As you may well know, the `Id` field is null in the `before` trigger  and yet you reference  `Id` in   your `start` and `execute` methods( `SELECT Id ...` ).

Answer (score 1):

There are many documents available online. few of things are:

http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2013/02/force-com-batch-apex-and-large-data-volumes.html

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: How to call the batch class from before trigger???